# How to remove row on click on confirm message true?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp gridview. On row databound I add onclick event to view item details. I have also delete button. The problem is **When I click item delete, it deletes item but also redirect to item preview page.** It should not do a postback and redirect

here is my code

```
 protected void Grid_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

                e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = String.Format("location.href='" + "/Url/page.aspx?id=" + "{0}", DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id") + "'");
            }
```

delete button

```
public void GvDeleteHabit(object source, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandName);
    Delete(id);
}


<asp:LinkButton OnCommand="Delete" title="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
CommandName='<%# Eval("Id")%>' runat="server" ID="BtnDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

on client side I have confirm message. So what I'm trying to achieve is when user click delete button and Yes, I need to remove onclick event from row and delete item.

if user click No stop page from loading. so user can click somewhere on row and view details of item

Comment: Find and alter the code doing the redirect? I don't see anything provided that would doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `javascript:` from `OnClientClick`. It's only needed if javascript is used in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that even when you click "Delete" is still registers as a click event on the row, which in turn fires off the redirect. You should put your redirect into a function, and pass in the source of the click event. If the source is your button, exit the function.

```
onRowClick = function(source){
   if (source.element.type == "button") // this may not be correct, but you get the point
       return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item');
   //do your redirect here
}

e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "onRowClick(this);";
```

AND in your HTML markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnCommand="Delete" title="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:return onRowClick(this);"
CommandName='<%# Eval("Id")%>' runat="server" ID="BtnDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have onclick handler on row also, you have to basically stop the event propagation on delete button click, try this it will solve the problem.

**ASPX Change**

```
<asp:LinkButton OnCommand="Delete" title="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:return confrimDelete(e);"
CommandName='<%# Eval("Id")%>' runat="server" ID="BtnDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Add this method in any of your js file or on the page**

```
function confirmDelete(){
   var event = e || window.event;
   if (event.stopPropagation) {
     event.stopPropagation();
   } else {
     event.cancelBubble = true;
   } 

   return confirm('Do you want to delete?');
}
```